# Pass element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular6

This code below gives out an error of " Type 'number[]' cannot be used as an index type" i want to pass that array of elements assign this.img correctly. how do i go about it?

```js
const imgArr = [0, 1, 2, 3]
this.img = data.included.main_images[imgArr].link.href;
```

Comment: Please click "Run" in the snippet editor before saving and adding to the post. When I click Run code snippet here, I just see `data is not defined`. Please include what `data`, `included`, and `main_images` are. The error message is also telling you something important; you can't access the things all at once. You'll need to use a loop.

Comment: The `imgArr` is an array and you're using it as an index.

Comment: thats why im asking whats better way of getting the index ?

Answer (score 0):

Index of array must be integer(ex:data.included.main_images[imgArr[0]]).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it helps

```js
  var data = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
  var indexes = [1,2,3]
  var y = data.filter(x => filterFunction(x, data))
  console.log(y)

  function filterFunction(x, data){
    return indexes.includes(data.indexOf(x))
  }
```